# libiconv.so: has text relocations error in cn1

Tags: codenameone

I've used zbarscanner lib in cn1 and it worked fine. I have recently updated the app and has the following bug that cause app crash. The error occured in nougat nokia 5 device. I checked the previous version of the app which works fine.

```
02-08 16:24:58.792 592-592/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.capitaleyenepal.lenovo, PID: 592
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: /data/app/com.capitaleyenepal.lenovo-2/lib/arm/libiconv.so: has text relocations
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:989)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1562)
at com.dm.zbar.android.scanner.ZBarScannerActivity.<clinit>(ZBarScannerActivity.java:28)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1079)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2558)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2727)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1478)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem with recent updates of Android and the [little monkey QR code scanner](https://github.com/littlemonkeyltd/QRScanner). The solution is to get a newly compiled version of the library that fixes that issue and integrate it into the cn1lib. I think you should open an issue on that project.

Comment: https://github.com/littlemonkeyltd/QRScanner/issues/8 
I think cn1 has shifted to build sdk 23. This issue doesn't appear if target sdk version is 22 in the build.gradle. Is there any way I can do that before the issue is solved in the library. I only have professional subscription...

Comment: We shifted to 23 years ago, little monkey was also updated a while back. Right now we just don't have the resources to do that as the 4.0 release is looming and we're busy pushing back fixes and enhancements that won't make it.

Comment: I had opened an issue for the barcode scanner issue about a month ago. Will it be solved? https://github.com/littlemonkeyltd/QRScanner/issues/8

Comment: You can try patching it using the `so` files from https://github.com/tjwoon/csZBar/pull/39

Comment: How can I patch a library in cn1? How to use so files in cn1? I've no idea. Can you give me some hints? I've never done it before.

Comment: Fork the code in github and check out your fork. There is a .so file within you will need to build a new version of that .so file or find one on the web by Googling your error. Replace that file. Run ant jar on the project (or use NetBeans to build it) replace the cn1lib in your project with the newly built one. Test it. If it works commit the new `.so` file and press the "Pull Request" button in the github site.

Comment: I'm so so sorry. I didn't find any .so file here: https://github.com/littlemonkeyltd/QRScanner

Comment: It's packaged within https://github.com/littlemonkeyltd/QRScanner/blob/master/native/android/ZBarScannerLibrary.aar I'm not sure how Nick generated that. Might be worth writing to him to see if he has that project up somewhere.

Comment: Sory, I didn't get u.

Comment: Google has a special format for packaging libraries called AAR. Nick (the author of that cn1lib) must have packed that native library inside the AAR file using an Android Studio project. That project might be already on github or he might have forgotten to commit it. I suggest asking him directly through social media

Comment: I don't find access to the Nick (auther's) social media.. can you please share his mail id, fb or twitter or anything?

Comment: I don't really know, you can look through the discussion forum or try contacting little monkey directly: https://www.littlemonkey.co.nz/about-us/the-company/ 
Notice you can also switch barcode scanning solutions e.g. the more expensive but more powerful https://github.com/shannah/cn1-codescan-scandit

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a late reply but as I have come to the same issue I am posting confirmation that the issue can be solved.
In summary, for me using the ZBar library through QRScanner from the QRScanner.cn1lib library was working fine and then stopped working, with the same error that I could see from the android logs as fatal level error (libiconv.so: has text relocations).

The following has been done (I am using the latest vs of CodenameOne):

1. Remove build hint android.xapplication (containing the ZBarScannerActivity)
2. Remove cn1-codescan.cn1lib and QRScanner.cn1lib, refresh project lib (not entirely sure that this was necessary, but anyway the stubs file was newer on the repos)
3. Download latest cn1-codescan.cn1lib and QRScanner.cn1lib, refresh project lib
4. Download .so compiled files from the above link
5. Manual copy each couple of files into the respective architecture
   folders, within the ZBarScannerLibrary.aar
6. Codenameone build for android

It is now working again.

Thanks Shai for your advice by email re. the build hint.